# asp.net core 2.0 custom input time {mm:ss.fff}

Tags: datetime, asp.net-core, format, timespan

Is it possible to define a custom mask or format for a DateTime or TimeSpan into an input box in razor view? (in this case looking for {mm:ss.fff}
I've tried a number of combinations in my model including;

```
    [Required (ErrorMessage ="please add a time")]
        [Display(Name = "Clocked Time")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0: mm:ss.fff}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)] 
         public TimeSpan? Clockedtime { get; set; }
```

Comment: What happened? What didn't work? The code you have should be sufficient, but there's other problems that can arise. For example, if you're using an input with type `time`, it won't be able to bind the value.

Comment: Basically nothing happened with the above. I experimented with DataType.Time (and type="time")  which would give the html time mask. But with the above I got nothing.

Comment: You might need to remove the space after the colon in the format string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will struggle to get a format/input mask for a TimeSpan. Your best option, I think, is to use a string as the input type and apply a regular expression to that.

```
[Required (ErrorMessage ="please add a time")]
[Display(Name = "Clocked Time")]
[RegularExpression(@"^(60|([0-5][0-9])):(60|([0-5][0-9]))(\.[0-9]*)$", ErrorMessage = "Must be in format hh:mm.fff")]
public String ClockedtimeString { get; set; }

private TimeSpan Clockedtime => TimeSpan.Parse(ClockedtimeString);
```

This should provide validation in your client side if the user inputs an incorrect value.
You can probably tweak the regular expression to better suit your needs (it's not my area of expertise).

In your controller/razor page you can reference the `Clockedtime` property, which should contain the parsed value.